# Not able to Login FB SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've integrated FB SDK and Im able to login with my device.

Problem arise when I distribute the app (ad-hoc), other people cant login.

Anyone know what's wrong with it? Why it is working in my device but not other devices?

EDIT:
I've figured out, it is because I was asking for "publish_action" permission during authentication. It doesn't work on iOS 6.0 devices

Comment: Are there any messages or errors?

Comment: Can other people login on your device? Can you login on other devices?

Comment: Is your app in sandbox mode?

Comment: I've figured out what's wrong with it and I've edited my post with answer :) Thanks